# LINQ - Left join with LinqToEntities using POCO in EF4

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, poco

I am having alot of troubles with my JOIN, I dont know if it depends on the EDM or if its just the LINQ-query.

When I try this T-SQL in SSMS it works like a charm:

> select g.Id, g.Title, p.Platform_short
>   from games as g
>   left outer join Platforms as p on g.PlatformId = p.Id

but when I try to translate the T-SQL to LINQ, with this:

The problem I get is that the Platform == null

I have tried different approaches but then I get duplicates.

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now, and I'm new to EF.

```
var games = (from g in ctx.Games
                         join p in ctx.Platforms
                         on g.Platform.Id equals p.Id
                         select new 
                         {
                             Id = g.Id,
                             Title = g.Title,
                             Platform = g.Platform,                                 
                         });
```

Heres is the whole method:

```
public ICollection<Game> GetGames()
    {            
        using(xContext ctx = new xContext())
        {                
            ICollection<Game> col = new Collection<Game>();

            var games = (from g in ctx.Games
                         join p in ctx.Platforms
                         on g.Platform.Id equals p.Id
                         select new 
                         {
                             Id = g.Id,
                             Title = g.Title,
                             Platform = g.Platform,                                 
                         });

            foreach (var g in games)
            {
                Game game = new Game();
                game.Id = g.Id;
                game.Title = g.Title;
                game.Platform = g.Platform;                    
                col.Add(game);
            }

            return col;

        }
    }
```

My GamePoco is having a Platform-property and is one-to-one relationship in the EDM.

Hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is purpose of your left join when result doesn't have anything from joined enity set?

Try this:

```
var games = (from g in ctx.Games
             join p in ctx.Platforms
             on g.Platform.Id equals p.Id into joinTable
             from j in jointTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new 
             {
                 Id = g.Id,
                 Title = g.Title,
                 Platform = j.PlatformShort                                 
             });
```

This works only in EFv4.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I think it worked, Is it possible to get the whole Platform obj instead of just Platform_short ? Platform is a sublass inside the Game obj.

Comment: Try to assign just `j` to `Platform`.

Comment: I also tried "Select new Game { .. } But then i get this error "The entity or complex type 'xModel.Game' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."